# Android recycling Button backgroundDrawable still causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have some `CustomButton`, and at some point, a background is drawn from a base64String into a `BitmapDrawable`, which is applied to the `CustomButton`. Within the total lifespan of the application, this can happen multiple times. This caused a `OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`, and after some digging on StackOverflow, this happened because the `Bitmaps` were not recycled. So I tried to handle this with some code that is executed each time another background was applied (this code comes from the `CustomButton` class):

```
public void recycleBackground() {
    BitmapDrawable bd = null;
    Drawable bg = getBackground();
    if (bg != null) {
        bg.setCallback(null);
        if (bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            bd = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
            if (!bd.getBitmap().isRecycled()) bd.getBitmap().recycle();
    }
    bd = null;   //just precautionous
    bg = null;   //also just a precaution
}
```

Yet, the memory is slowly (because background images are not all that large) but surely flooded. **What am I missing or doing wrong?** I combined the above code from some different questions/answers from SO. I can find a lot on recycling `Bitmaps`, not so much on the recycling of `Drawables`. Maybe that's what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this in a tight loop?  Maybe the GC doesn't have time to run?  I like your recycleBackground() method, unbinding the callback and recycling is the right way to go.  Have you tried MAT?  Are you sure the problem is not elsewhere, e.g. your base 64 string reader?

Comment: the GC has plenty of time. I update all buttons one by one, call the recycle method on each of them and have the Controller Thread wait for 3 seconds, plus the images are quite small. The base64reader should not be the problem, but ill try. I havent tried MAT, I hoped eclipse would provide one, but haven't found one there. Thanks.

Comment: This article focuses on Eclipse. http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html